# I am trying to amplify push however getting timedout error what can be the issue?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am trying out aws amplify with react native by following this tutorial :

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/react

I was able to push a few days back, then I think I happened to update the cli and then amplify stopped working.

For example, amplify push is throwing the following error:

```
$ amplify push
- Fetching updates to backend environment: dev from the cloud.
(node:18960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 169.254.169.254:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
(node:18960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:18960) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

$ npm info amplify version
0.0.11

$ npm info aws-amplify version
3.0.18

aws-amplify/cli : 4.22.0
```

I couldn't find a solution for this on the internet hence kindly help.

Comment: Similar issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/4488